# JSXGraph create codependent board elements

Tags: jsxgraph

I would like to create a point and a line that are codependent, so that changing the position of one changes the other and vice versa. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to create event handlers for both elements. Here is an example for two codependent points:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
                            boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5],
              axis: true
          });
var A = board.create('point', [-3, 2]);     
var B = board.create('point', [ 3, 2]);     

A.on('drag', function() {
        B.moveTo([B.X(), A.Y()]);
});

B.on('drag', function() {
        A.moveTo([A.X(), B.Y()]);
});
```

It can be see in action at https://jsfiddle.net/vcL7aepo/204/ .